# how to do alot of calculation once in flutter stateless widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having issue with Flutter constructor. I'm coming form javascript background and I am confused why Dart is this much hard to code.

first let me tell how it would look like in ts/js

```
import {availableMeals} from "MealService";

type MealFilter={isGlutenFree:boolean};
type Meal=unknown; //just for brevity

class GridPage{

    _filteredMeal: Meal[]
    constructor(public filter?: MealFilter ){
        
        this._filteredMeal= availableMeals.filter(x=> {
            if (filter==null){
                return true;
            }
            
            if(filter.isGlutenFree && !x.isGlutenFree){
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
        // and alot of other calculations
    }
}
```

I'm trying to convert the same thing to a flutter widget and I'm failing

my first try was to write something like this

```
class GridPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const GridPage({super.key, this.filter = const []}){
    filteredFoods = availableMeals.where((meal) {
      if (filter == null) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }).toList();;
  }

  final List<FilterModel>? filter;
  final List<Meal> filteredFoods
}
```

i'm getting error

> Const constructors can't have a body.
> Try removing either the 'const' keyword or the body.

if I remove the `const` then I get error

> 'filteredFoods' can't be used as a setter because it's final.
> Try finding a different setter, or making 'filteredFoods' non-final.

if I remove the `final` from constructor then I get this error:

> This class (or a class that this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields aren't final: GridPage.filteredFoods

so I tried to find a way to keep the `final` and `const`

```
class GridPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const GridPage({super.key, this.filter = const []});

  final List<FilterModel>? filter;
  final List<Meal> filteredFoods= availableMeals.where((meal) {
      if (filter == null) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }).toList();;
}
```

now I'm getting error that

> The instance member 'filter' can't be accessed in an initializer.
> Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

so reluctantly I turned to colon syntax, to be frank I don't know how that could scale for big calculation that need to be done once only in the constructor

```
class GridPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const GridPage({super.key, this.filter = const []})
      : filteredFoods= availableMeals.where((meal) {
           if (filter == null) {
              return true;
           }
           return false;
        }).toList();

  final List<FilterModel>? filter;
  final List<Meal> filteredFoods;
}
```

I tried to wrap the assignment into a function since there are many of them

```
class GridPage extends StatelessWidget {
  GridPage({super.key, this.filter = const []})
      : init(filter);
```

getting error

> Expected an assignment after the field name.
> To initialize a field, use the syntax 'name = value'

so now my question is how to handle if I have many calculation need to be done once in constructor time? also apparently can't use anything with body (for, while, if).
I don't want to switch to statefull just because of this.
I don't like the idea of moving this to `build` method too, why I have to calculate the list when filter haven't changed yet?
is any way I can hold to stateless and do all calculations once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `const` keyword from the constructor and add `late` modifier to the `filteredFoods` field. Using `late` modifier on a `final` field allows you to assign value to the field later, but only once.

```dart
class GridPage extends StatelessWidget {
  GridPage({super.key, this.filter = const []}) {
    filteredFoods = availableMeals.where((meal) {
      if (filter == null) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }).toList();
  }

  final List<FilterModel>? filter;
  late final List<Meal> filteredFoods;
}
```

More about the late final variables: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-final-variables

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to do the calculation and other logic outside of constructor.

That would mean using stateful widget and doing calculations either in `initState()` or using a `FutureBuilder`.

If not, my suggestion is make filtered foods a `getter` instead of a final property.

eg:

```dart
List<Meal> get filteredFoods {
  if(filters==null||filters!.isEmpty()) return availableFoods;
  
  return availableFoods.where((e){
    bool shouldReturnFood = false;
    
    // do other comparisons 
    // I'm using the variable to keep track of whether to return the current item or not
    return shouldReturnFood ;
  });
}
```

Comment: I agree with the last approach: Having it defined as a getter is the clearest solution. If there's a simple check, you can also do it in the constructor line, similar to (for example) the approach that is taken in [the named constructor example in the docs](https://dart.dev/language/constructors#named-constructors)

Comment: thanks, but a getter will calculate the result on every usage. for example if I have 10 usage of `filterFoods` it will calculate the list 10 times, I don't think there will be easy way to cache it so it calculate it only once

Comment: if all usages of the getter would be the same value I suppose you could pass the list itself after calculation to the widget. Which means you do the calculation in the object instantiation or before it. But i would still say go with stateful as you can use a loading screen till you compute the final list... especially when the items in list are really LARGE in number